# Can't Connect to SQL Server 2008 via sqlmd

Tags: sql-server

I want to schedule a backup for my database for SQL 2008 express. I found a nice stored procedure for this job. I made a bat file for it and I want to run it, but the following sqlcmd statement fails :

```
sqlcmd -S '.\SQLEXPRESS' -Q "EXEC sp_BackupDatabases @databaseName='BonusPoint', @backupLocation='C:\DBBackup\', @backupType='F'"
```

I also tried with the username and the password:

```
sqlcmd -S '.\SQLEXPRESS' -U 'sa' -P '*******' -Q "EXEC sp_BackupDatabases @databaseName='BonusPoint', @backupLocation='C:\DBBackup\', @backupType='F'"
```

But I'm getting the following error:

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=29za3gn&s=5

The database is in the same machine and I can connect to the database via SSMS.

EDIT:

Finaly I succesfully connected to the DB via sqlcmd with the following statement:

```
sqlcmd -Snp:\\.\pipe\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS\sql\query
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your original attempts is that you had -S '.\SQLEXPRESS' where SQLCMD doesn't like the single quotes. it you would of used double quotes, such as -S ".\SQLEXPRESS", it would of likely worked.

Comment: You're right it's working just fine. The interesting in it is that I found the snippet from a random forum and there they saying that the snippet is working fine. Is there some differences between the sqlcmd versions?

Comment: I can't say for certain whether there is a difference in versions of SQLCMD in regards to this. But I just did a quick test though comparing the regular command prompt with the powershell prompt. It looks like the powershell prompt works just fine with the single quotes where the command prompt does not. I suspect it is just a difference in how the two different prompts treat quotes.